# Is there any way to modify the balancing mode of a GKE native public Ingress and what is the default balancing mode?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I'm having a really hard time finding this in the docs. How do GKE native Ingresses balance traffic? I'm asking about the public GKE native Ingresses that would be pointing to a ClusterIP service.

Does it just use the standard round robin balancing that k8s ClusterIP uses?

If I'm using a GKE native public Ingress it *appears* I can modify the BackendConfig to set `balancingMode` per this: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#lb-config.

But I see virtually no other official docs specifically mentioning the `balancingMode` field.

VPC native clusters with GKE native Ingresses use NEGs. In [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#balancing-mode-lb) it says:

> The Application Load Balancers support either RATE or UTILIZATION
> balancing modes for instance group backends, RATE balancing mode for
> zonal NEGs with GCE_VM_IP_PORT endpoints, and RATE balancing mode for
> hybrid NEGs (NON_GCP_PRIVATE_IP_PORT endpoints). For any other type of
> supported backend, balancing mode must be omitted.

Do VPC native clusters use `zonal NEGs with GCE_VM_IP_PORT endpoints` and if so does that mean only RATE is supported per the chart on that page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the default behavior for clusterIP services is also a round-robin load balancer. GKE ingress and load balancer have similar load balancing behavior.

Regarding BackendConfig, if you will check its [feature](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#:%7E:text=GA-,BackendConfig,-Backend%20service%20timeout) it doesnt yet support Balancing Mode, possibly that is the reason why there are no docs showing how you can configure BackendConfig with Balancing mode.

About the VPC native cluster with GKE Ingress, it seems that your prediction is also correct, replicating this concern and same with what you said, RATE is it seems that is supported. I also bumped in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#creating_an_ingress_resource) and there is no configuration that is related to Balancing mode.

Comment: So if I have a gke native ingress fronting a ClusterIp service is it using round robin or RATE to balance traffic to the pods?

Comment: clusterIP in GKE is not round robin, but random, as GKE uses iptables proxy mode (on linux). You can read more at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#proxy-modes